# Is it possible for VS 2019 to use more than 4GB RAM?

Tags: windows-10, memory, 64-bit, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

From time to time I see that in my computer ( 64 bit Windows 10) `Task Manager, Processes` tab that VS 2019 uses more than 4GB-- sometimes it can go up to 5GB, but not more than that. (I use VS 2019 together with Resharper plugin.)

I suspect that this is because my laptop has only 12GB, and Chrome and other processes also take a substantial amount of memory, so that's why VS 2019 can't take more than 5GB, other processes also use memory. I'm thinking about upgrading my laptop to 32 GB or so.

But when I think about it, I can't make sense of the whole thing:

1. VS 2019 is still a 32 bit application, which means that [it should be able to get at most 4GB RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/639562/3834), even on a 64 bit machine with unlimited memory RAM. Then how is it possible that I see that it uses more than 4GB in the Process tab in Task Manager?
2. Will it help ( in terms of less frequency of VS 2019 restart, and snappier VS 2019 performance) if I upgrade my RAM from 12 to 32 GB?

Comment: know nothing about VS2019 but a 32 bit application can use more then 4 gigs of RAM through PAE - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/physical-address-extension

Comment: Visual Studio consists of many many processes nowadays.

Comment: @DanielB, and so?

Comment: And so it is not bound by the regular 4GB-per-process limit anyway. Also, only the Detail tab in Task Manager shows real, per-process metrics.

Comment: @DanielB, so you are saying that *only* the 32 processes under the `Details` tab in Task Manager are subjected to the 4GB limits ? And also therefore, upgrading my RAM will definitely help?

Comment: @davidgo: PAE is not something an application uses, it is for the OS. You were probably thinking of Address Windowing Extensions and maybe the Large Address Aware flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr: Yes, more memory will definitely help. A modern Windows development system should have at least 24 GiB of RAM.

---

Visual Studio has long since been split into multiple processes. That means it can easily take advantage of more than 4 GiB of RAM.

Additionally, Visual Studio is “Large Address Aware”. That way it has more space for “user data”. Usually, this space is limited to *2 GiB* because of the system/user memory space split. You can more about it [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/virtual-address-spaces). Virtual memory is a complicated topic.

Unfortunately, memory accounting isn’t easy either. Visual Studio uses lots of shared memory. Task Manager does not even attempt to account for shared memory. It uses the “Active private working set” memory figure which does not include shared memory at all.

Task Manager also does not group all Visual Studio processes into the expandable entry you see on the “Processes” tab.

Comment: Indeed. Open task manager, and you'll see a large number of `dev.exe` processes.